# Is it necessary (or advisable) to add CSS styling to the HTML element?

Tags: html, css

When looking at other people's code (or many CSS resets), I see the `html` element addressed with basic styling (like `height: 100%`) and sometimes I see it ignored completely.  In my experimentation there is no difference, but I am not sure if I am missing something.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593106/styling-the-html-element-in-css) they give the example of

```
html,body{
   min-height: 101%;
}
```

to keep scrollbars visible (but no other definitive answer).  Other than a hack like this, is there any specific reason to style the html element?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you asked already 30 question, why didn't you marked any good answer as "Correct"? It's a way to say 'thanks' here on SO and a way for other users to immediately see from a bunch of other answers which one helped you in your task.

Comment: See [Should global css styles be set on the html element or the body element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565942) and [What's the difference in applying CSS to html, body, and *?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187569)

Comment: Some examples of when to apply styles to `html` vs `body` can be found here: [Applying a background to <html> and/or <body>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541) and [height: 100% or min-height: 100% for html and body elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555682)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the major reason i can think of is that, for specifying `height` in `%` the elements parent needs to have a height set explicitly.

Assume you've a container `<div>` which you need to be of `100%` height and *responsive*. simply applying `height:100%` won't  work unless you specify a height for it's parent `<body>`.

Hence we'll apply `height:100%` for the `<body>` -  Now, this won't work since `<body>`'s parent doesn't have a height set explicitly - which is our `<html>` element.

Hence we apply

```
html{
 height:100%;
}
```

...!

This is not required if your design is not responsive , i.e if you're setting fixed dimensions in *pixels*

Comment: Does setting `html {height: 100%}` actually set it explicitly? (it does seem like it)
And basically what you are saying is that it is only necessary to style the html element if you are using a responsive design?

Answer (score 0):

This is used for making height:100% relative to the viewport height.

Comment: So does this mean that, if you do not make `html{height:100%}` the html will not take up 100% of the viewport?

Comment: If you don't make it 100%, then if you set body 100% and a child div to 100% they wont be the actual height of the viewport.

Comment: Of what would they be 100%?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, it is the html element that displays scrollbars. So if you don't want to display scrollbars at all for some reason you would need to hide overflow on that element.

More information about the html element [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101486/does-the-html-element-have-a-default-margin-or-padding-in-any-browser-since-n)

Comment: Yes, I read that post too. Best answer says that it only has to do with scroll bars (so style `html` if you care about scrollbars, but it also says, `(use it) to get 100% height and width`  again, making me feel like it is necessary to style the html element if I do want height and width to be 100% of viewport

Comment: I can only conclude that the html element is strange. A quick test applying a border to the html element in a page that has little content shows that the element doesn't fill the viewport. But applying a background color to the element shows the entire viewport with the background color. So which actually represents the "container" that is the html element? Setting height of the html element to 100% actually makes it taller than the viewport.

Comment: Yes, I am seeing some weird things when using / omitting css styling on html while using flexbox.  I think I am always going to set height to 100% from here on out

Comment: Dave, the behavior that you're observing is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body/10947583#10947583