# How to align this html layout properly?

Tags: html, css, layout, alignment, margin

Hi iam trying to remove these white spaces (green circles in image) , but i dont the best way to do it. 
Even i can do margin-left  -ve value and width more than 100%  but is there any way to solve this issue in proper way .

Here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Hachi</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_rec.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<style>
#container{
font-family: "proxima-nova", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
       font-weight: normal;
       color:#414141;
       -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
       height: auto;
       width: 100%;

}
#header{
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: red;
}
#left_panel{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
/*    height: 400px;
*/  background-color: green;
}
#right_panel{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
/*    height: 400px;
*/  background-color: blue;
}
#bottom_logos{
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="left_panel">
kjjjhjfhklhhhkh
dfdsfdsfsdfdsf
</div>
<div id="right_panel">
ewrewrewrewrewr
ewrwerewrwerewr
</div>
<div id="bottom_logos"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those margins are part of the way the browser renders the content by default.

You can remove them by using `body, html { margin: 0px; }`.

I also recommend you use a [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/).

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/arXE3/)</kbd>

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**Edit** :

Here no need to add `html { margin:0; padding:0; }` as they don't have any default browser styles. From [Does the <html> element have a default margin or padding in any browser, since normalize.css doesn't reset it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101486/does-the-html-element-have-a-default-margin-or-padding-in-any-browser-since-n)

Comment: @ChristophBühler : Yeah, u r right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101486/does-the-html-element-have-a-default-margin-or-padding-in-any-browser-since-n

Answer (score 2):

Try to Reset CSS like:

```
html,body{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

or you can find full reset **[here](http://www.cssreset.com/)**

Answer (score 1):

Write a CSS style for body containing padding: 0; and margin: 0;

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You need to declare `margin: 0` for your `body` and `html` both.

http://jsfiddle.net/appleBud/MweUe/

Hope it works.